# maven-compiler-plugin does not do annotation processing when fork=true is specified?

Tags: maven, annotations, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm using `maven-compiler-plugin` in a maven project to perform annotation processing on my code. It was working until I added a `<fork>true</fork>` configuration option.

The *pom.xml* file has the following:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Add dependency on the annotation processor -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-processor</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The *my-processor-1.0.jar* file contains a *META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor* file so that it can be discovered by the `javac` compiler at runtime.

When I run *mvn clean compile* with this configuration, I see that the annotation processor runs and generated code is put into the *target\generated-sources\annotations* directory, as expected.

But if I add a `<fork>true</fork>` option to the plugin configuration, then I observe that the annotation processor does not run and no code is present in the *target\generated-sources\annotations* directory.

I tried this with `maven-compiler-plugin` version 2.5.1, 3.0 and 3.1 (with the 3.x versions I had to add a `<forceJavaCompilerUser>true</forceJavaCompilerUser>` option to the configuration so that the annotation processor jar would be discovered).

I also tried specifying the annotation processor explicitly:

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <annotationProcessors>
    <annotationProcessor>x.y.z.MyProcessor</annotationProcessor>
  </annotationProcessors>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Again, for version 2.5.1, 3.0, and 3.1, the annotation processor would be invoked if the configuration option did not specify forking. When `<fork>true</fork>` option is specified, then the annotation processor would not run.

I also added the `x.y.z:my_processor` dependency outside of the `maven-compiler-plugin` dependency, to make sure that the annotation processor dependency was loaded.

Should annotation processing still work when the `maven-compiler-plugin` is configured with `<fork>true</fork>`? Or am I configuring the plugin incorrectly?

Note that I do not want to split the compilation into separate executions (e.g. one execution to compile without annotation processing, using `<fork>true</fork>`, and another execution to only do annotation processing, using `<fork>false</fork>`, since the second execution recompiles the entire source again, which is bad when dealing with thousands of source files, unless there is a way to get around this).

I am using JDK 1.7.0_45.

**Edit #1**

Actually the solution was to move the processor dependency out of the plugin's dependency and into the normal dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-processor</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 ...
</dependencies>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
      <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugin>
```

I thought I had tested this but I might have been looking for console output (that will not appear when the process is forked) instead of looking for the existence of generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution was to move the processor dependency out of the plugin's dependency and into the normal dependencies. See Edit #1 in the original post.

Although, weirdly, I get a compilation error when the dependency is added vs when the dependency is not added. Without the dependency, I see a compiler warning about using an internal proprietary API. When the annotation processor dependency is added, that warning is treated as an error. I can't see any `-Werror` option in the compiler options that would treat warnings as errors. When the annotation processor dependency is removed, the compilation passes with a warning. Scratching my head over this one ...

Comment: I have the same problem - I have a JAR (artifact **apt**) = my annotation processor, and I use it in plugin (Mojo in artifact **apt-plugin**) that merely runs Javac tool using this annotation processor. I use it in project X. When the dependency to **apt** is in projects dependency, it's OK. But when I just use it in plugins `depencies/dependency` it doesn't work. Maven model says that `dependencies` in `plugin` are... "Additional dependencies that this project needs to introduce to the plugin's classloader." But when I debug the plugin, it does not offer my dependency in any project.get...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`compilerArgs`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs) option to pass the `-processor` options to the javac when it is invoked by maven in forked mode.

Comment: Thanks ... actually the solution requires moving the processor dependency out of the 'maven-compiler-plugin' section and into the 'dependencies' section. The '-processor' option had no effect otherwise.

Comment: Ah okay. You might want to put that as an official answer and accept it so that anyone having the same issue can easily find the solution (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).